# define a scope at run time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have models `Gateway` and `GatewayType`, and I am looking for

```
Gateway.<gateway_type.name> # => Gateway.where(:gateway_type_id => gateway_type.id)
```

Now this `<gateway_type.name>` scope should get created at run time, similar to adding class/instance level methods at run time using defined_method like below

```
class Object
  def metaclass
    class << self
      self
    end
  end
end

# adding class level methods
GatewayType.all.each do |type|
  # adding methods to Gateway
  Gateway.metaclass.class_eval do
    define_method "all_#{type.name}" do
      Gateway.where(:gateway_type_id => type.id)
    end
  end
end
```

I do not want to go with above approach, as it wont allow me to add `all_xyzs` in between `where` or other scope like

```
Gateway.scope1.all_xyzs.scope2
```

So... is there any way to have `scope` defined at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all `Gateway` objects for a particular `GatewayType`, why not do this?

```
gateway_type = GatewayType.find(id)
gateway_type.gateways
```

I assume in this case that you have `has_many :gateways` on `GatewayType`. The association methods in Rails would allow you to restrict queries to a subset of gateways for a particular `GatewayType` object.

Comment: you are right, but still for reasons, 1) I want to know whether we could add scopes at run time, 2) I would like to see code like "Gateway.scope1.xyzs.scope2"

Comment: Yes you can add scopes at runtime. Just call `scope` method on the class you want to add a scope to.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out a lot of 'eval' and other stuff I got the following working
just replacing above defined method as

```
  define_method "#{type.name}" do
    where(:gateway_type_id => type.id)
  end
```

and its working as per I want `Gateway.scope1.xyzs.scope2`